# Orrange barrier around button

Tags: html, css

When I press a text button, an orange barrier forms around it. How do I fix it?

[Picture of the problem in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcVxC.png)

Here is the CSS code of the button.

```
.aboutbtn {
border: none;
background-color: inherit;
padding: 14px 28px;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
}
```

And here is the HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <title>kasacast</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="header">
       <img src="images/logo.png" alt="kasacast logo" class="logo">
       <button class="aboutbtn">about</button>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add outline-color:white when the btn is focused

```js
function myPrint(){
console.log('no color!');
}
```

```css
.aboutbtn {
border:none;
background-color: inherit;
padding: 14px 28px;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
}

.aboutbtn:focus{
outline-color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <title>kasacast</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="header">
       <img src="images/logo.png" alt="kasacast logo" class="logo">
       <button class="aboutbtn" onclick="myPrint()">about</button>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```